# Minitab - Binomial Probabilty results in 0 regardless of input constant

Tags: probability, math-software

This is my first question here so please be patient if I make a mistake. I will try to correct it.

I am using minitab for a statistics class. I have to compute the binomial probability with n=60 and p=0.7. I am supposed to be computing for input constant = 60 however the answer I get is 0.00000 . When I change the input constant to 1 or 4 I still get 0.00000 . I am obviously doing something wrong/missing something. However when I input example questions from the textbook I got the correct answer. I would really appreciate any help/suggestions/advice/nudge in the right direction.

ETA I wanted it to compute the probability of 60 successes. However I'm not sure if I did it right. From what I understand the input constant is the number of successes?

Comment: I don't know what you asked Minitab to do. Compute the probability of $60$ successes? It is in the $10^{-10}$ range. Compute the probability of $60$ failures? That is I think less than $10^{-30}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. In my test cases I used the values 60 successes, 1 success and 4 successes. What I didn't think about was that the number for 1 or 4 successes would also be really small. When I kept getting answers of 0.0000000 I thought I was inputting the data wrong, however I now realize I was just interpreting it incorrectly.